# Converting numpy array to spark dataframe to input into MySQL (pyspark)

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using the JDBC driver, I was able to pull a table of data I had stored in MySQL into a spark dataframe.

I then ran the Statistic corr function from pyspark mllib on the dataframe (after some transformations) and was able to get a correlation matrix (type numpy.ndarray) similar to this:

[[1.0, 0.95, 0.77], [0.95, 1.0, 0.34], [0.77, 0.34, 1.0]]

How can I take this matrix and create a dataframe like the one below so that I can input that back into MySQL:

```
                Attribute 1   Attribute 2  Attribute 3
    Attribute 1     1.0          0.95          0.77
    Attribute 2     0.95         1.0           0.34
    Attribute 3     0.77         0.34          1.0
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: To clarify, the type of the array returned by Statistics corr function is a numpy.ndarray. This seems to have an impact on how the schema for the dataframe is formulated.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually multiple ways to save your data back to MySQL. Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

corr_matrix = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 0.95, 0.77], [0.95, 1.0, 0.34], [0.77, 0.34, 1.0]])
df = spark.createDataFrame(corr_matrix, schema=['Att 1', 'Att 2', 'Att 3'])

df.write.jdbc(url, table)
```

where url is a JDBC URL and table is the name of table in the external database

Comment: If I already have an existing dataframe with the schema I want could I utilize that instead of manually retyping it out all again? If so, how would I go about doing that. This will help make my code much more flexible. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to implement your solution above and I get the following error message: 'Can not infer schema for type: <type numpy.ndarray>

Comment: It seems that it can't infer your type since it is still a numpy array. Spark DF requires a RDD, tuple, list or pandas DF. So one way is for example to use pandas DF (see edited solution). Another way is to convert the numpy array to a list. And yes you can use an existing dataframe with the schema. For this please have a look at the documentation. I already gave you a good hint with the `spark.createDataFrame`.